# Basis of the taxonomic classification of viruses

Tags: virology, classification

The Wikipedia entry on [Virus Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_classification) contains the following statement:

> “Viruses are classified by phenotypic characteristics, such as
> morphology, nucleic acid type, mode of replication, host organisms,
> and the type of disease they cause.”

The use of such phenotypic characteristics for classification of plants, animals, and fungi ended with the discovery of DNA as the carrier of genetic information. At that time it began to be replaced by classification by genotype, so as to include evolutionary history.

Why would it appear that a similar approach has not been adopted towards viruses? Is it because there are no fossilized viruses?

Comment: Thanks for providing your suspicion David, feel free to google it

Comment: since some viruses do not have DNA that might be one reason.

Comment: Unless you are trolling, I think you will find that people such as @David (with nearly 24,000 reputation on here) will have a strong understanding of such basic concepts as phenotype and genotype.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my request for information. In order to attempt to rescue the question I have rewritten it in a less strident manner that reduces the (I am sure unintended) impression of superiority that it conveyed to me, at least. I have tried to improve the presentation of the quotation and made its attribution specific. I have also avoided the use of "we", which suggests a personalization which I, for one, find irritating. If you are willing to accept this modification I can proceed to address some of the points relating to classification of viruses.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that you are entirely incorrect in your statement that we classify "higher" organisms by genotype. Yes, that *may* be a part of it, but until the advent of high-throughput genetic sequencing in the last 20 years or so, we couldn't do this much. Before the development of these technologies, genetic analysis was largely limited to fragments sequenced by Sanger sequencing and various PCR or similar based analyses.

Almost all of botany, zoology, and microbiology is phenotypic in nature. For instance, you might have heard of [Eukaryotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eukaryote) and [Prokaryotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokaryote), two of the highest divisions in nature - these are split on the presence or absence of a nucleus in the cell, not on genetic content. Flowering plants are split into the presence or [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocotyledon) or [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicotyledon) cotyledons in their seeds. Animals can be split based on the presence if a [backbone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertebrate) or [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordate) The list goes on through almost all of [systematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematics)...

Likewise, we do similarly for viruses. For instance, the type of nuclear material is a major phenotypic feature that is easy to split them apart on; you won't find DNA viruses and RNA viruses in the same family of viruses, because they don't produce the same morphologies *and* have little genetic similarity.  So you *can* classify them by genetic sequencing and you would likely come up with similar phylogenies as the current system of phenotypic features. Indeed, so powerful are the higher groupings done by morphology, that we can now find small fragments of virus genome and identify which species they belong to or work out if they are novel through such things as [metagenomic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metagenomics)

Comment: Is it not true that vertebrata, invertebrata, eukaryota and prokaryota are monophyletic, thus grouped by genotype? And for this reason monocotyledon/dicotyledon is no longer an official Plantae classification due to them not being monophyletic? Thanks for the info on viruses, I didn’t realize that

Comment: @imrobert No - eukaryota covers everything from plants to animals to fungi. Prokaryota covers bacteria and archaea.